# MenuItem to open link with intent?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, button, menu

Ok,I'm creating an application that has a menu, and there are three menu items on is about one is to go to a webpage and one to exit the application.
The exit and about work fine but the webpage menuitem doesnt work, it force closes here is my code for the menus:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.about:
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.ABOUT"));
        return true;

    case R.id.facebook:
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("www.facebook.com"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);

        return true;




    }
    return false;
}
```

Could someone tell me whats wrong?

Comment: Can you post the logcat trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use like this

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse( "https://www.google.co.in" );
startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified `http://` scheme in your URI string.

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to go to the facebook application from the menu,it really easy!
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.ProfileTabHostActivity");
intent.putExtra("extra_user_id", "123456789l");
this.startActivity(intent);